How to use i18next nesting features with i18next-icu format
Im using i18next-icu for following icu format.
    {
      "nesting1": "1 $t(nesting2)",
      "nesting2": "2 $t(nesting3)",
      "nesting3": "3",
    }


    i18n.t("nesting1")
    // => expected to return
    1 2 3
    // => actual
    1 $t(nesting2)

this is not working in i18n-icu extended i18n inits
I checked the i18n instance and its nestingPrefix and nestingSuffix are "$t(" and ")" respectively.
